# Tensorflow version ''1.1.0' SKCompat AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am attempting to implement VGGnet using TF 1.1.0, using the MNIST CNN tutorial provided [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers). The error message I am receiving is:

```
AttributeError: 'SKCompat' object has no attribute 'evaluate'
```

This part of my code throws up the AttributeError:

```
#create estimator
vggnet_classifier = learn.SKCompat(learn.Estimator(model_fn=vggnet_model, model_dir= "/tmp/vgg_net"))

# Set up logging for predictions
tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=100)

#train model
vggnet_classifier.fit(
    x=X_train,
    y=y_train,
    batch_size=100,
    steps=2,
    monitors=[logging_hook])

# Configure the accuracy metric for evaluation
metrics = {
    "accuracy":
        learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn=tf.metrics.accuracy, prediction_key="classes"),}

# Evaluate the model and print results
eval_results = vggnet_classifier.evaluate(x=X_val, y=y_val, metrics=metrics)
print(eval_results)
```

I originally added the `SKCompat()` wrapper around `learn.Estimator` due to a deprecation warning, but I can't seem to find any information on how to use the wrapped estimator to evaluate the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to declare:

```
loss = None
train_op = None
```

in my vggnet_model function, which seems to be the source of the error. Removing learn.SKcompat() throws up the warning, but the model is training fine and running well now.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if there is any elegant solution now. Just as the OP points out, using the SKCompat() wrapper avoids the warnings, and it seems to be the thing to do in the future; but on the other hand the evaluate() function breaks that way.